# Error message while using Interrupts ARDUINO

Tags: arduino, interrupt-handling

I am making a basic computer and the chip that syncs everything together is an Attiny85.
This chip tells others when they can do things on the data bus.

The principle of how it works is that whenever pin PB0(labeled 11 in IDE or intPin in the code) is set HIGH, the ATtiny85 set all pins LOW then the corresponding pin of the next chip HIGH.

The problem is in the `attachPinToInterrupt()` statement.

I get this error message when I try to compile the code:
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Mac OS X), Board: "ATtiny25/45/85, ATtiny85, Internal 8 MHz"

```
/Users/alexandrebergeron/Documents/Arduino/computer/computerClock/computerClock.ino: In function 'void setup()':
computerClock:11:47: error: 'digitalPinToInterrupt' was not declared in this scope
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(intPin), procDone(), RISING);
                                           ^
exit status 1
'digitalPinToInterrupt' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Here's my code:

```
//common vars
volatile int priority = 0;

//pin numbers
const int intPin = 11;
const int cpuPin = 6;
const int videoPin = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(intPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(intPin), procDone(), RISING);
  pinMode(cpuPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(videoPin, OUTPUT);
}

void procDone() {
    digitalWrite(cpuPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(videoPin, LOW);
    switch(priority) {
        case 0:
            digitalWrite(cpuPin, HIGH);
            break;
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(videoPin, HIGH);
            break;
    }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I anybody could help me it would be very appreciated.

Because the chip is only doing that, can it be possible to do something like this?

```
bool clock = true;

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(intPin)==LOW) {
    if (clock==true) {
      procDone();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is not supported for given boards.

You can enable external interrupts of each pin by setting a correct bit in **PCMSK** register to 1. You also have to enable this kind of interrupts in **GIMSK** register (bit 5 and/or 6). I've found a nice example [here](https://thewanderingengineer.com/2014/08/11/pin-change-interrupts-on-attiny85/).

The code:

```
#include "avr/interrupt.h" 
volatile int value=0;

void setup() {
    GIMSK = 0b00100000;    // turns on pin change interrupts
    PCMSK = 0b00010011;    // turn on interrupts on pins PB0, PB1, &amp;amp; PB4
    sei();                 // enables interrupts
}

void loop() {
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    value = 1;             // Increment volatile variable
}
```

Comment: You said that it is not supported on some boards but I also tried to compile with Arduino Uno and Arduino Mega and I still got the same error message

Comment: So you changed the board in board manager to Uno/Mega? If yes, check if your paths in Arduino IDE are correct. If it's Mac related, I am afraid I can not help you, because I am using Win10. This solution should work on attiny.

Comment: I added a new code at the end of my question do you think it would work?

Comment: The code at the end will call procDone() function, if input is activated (low). But you are not using interrupts anymore... The  if (clock==true) condition will not affect the code since clock is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Spyro!

Your code is most correct, but unfortunately not all pins are available for the *External Interrupt* function. The digital pin 11 is not an external interrupt pin.

For the arduino pins, you would need to check the following link:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

For the ATTiny, you only have the external interrupt option on the pin entitled PB2:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7our.png)

Try changing the physical connection of your intPin from 11 to 2, for instance, in an arduino Uno, and run the code again:

```
//common vars
volatile int priority = 0;

//pin numbers
const int intPin = 2;
const int cpuPin = 6;
const int videoPin = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(intPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(intPin), procDone(), RISING);
  pinMode(cpuPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(videoPin, OUTPUT);
}

void procDone() {
    digitalWrite(cpuPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(videoPin, LOW);
    switch(priority) {
        case 0:
            digitalWrite(cpuPin, HIGH);
            break;
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(videoPin, HIGH);
            break;
    }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Or change the ATTiny connection from pin PB0 to PB2 and use the snippet JSC has provided, I believe it will work the same.

Let me know if this helps, I think it will solve the issue you're facing.

**Edit:
If there is nothing else that your arduino code does, and it's processing time is not long, why not just check the raising edge of your signal?

```
//common vars
volatile int priority = 0;
uint8_t btn_prev = HIGH;

//pin numbers
const int intPin = 2;
const int cpuPin = 6;
const int videoPin = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(intPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(cpuPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(videoPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t btn_state = digitalRead(intPin);

  if ( (btn_state == LOW) && (btn_prev == HIGH) {
     procDone();
  }
  btn_prev = btn_state;

}

void procDone() {
    if(priority == 0) {
       priority = 1;}
    else {
       priority = 0;}  
    digitalWrite(cpuPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(videoPin, LOW);
    switch(priority) {
        case 0:
            digitalWrite(cpuPin, HIGH);
            break;
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(videoPin, HIGH);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: on the diagram you showed, we clearly see PB2 as int0. On some pinouts, PB2 is labeled as pin 11 and on others labeled as pin 2. I tried both and it is not working.

Comment: I saw on the Arduino reference site that attachPinToInterrupt() is not necessary and that I could only write intPin as the first parameter, but not recommended. The compiler says done, but I have doubts on this solution.

Comment: does the remainder of your microcontroller code take too much processing time? Because, if not, I think you can achieve the same result with the code I've edited in.

Comment: The only processing it does is set a pin or another HIGH to be sure none chip on the computer is processing on the bus at the same time than another one.

Comment: when a function is called, does the loop() function stops during its execution or it continues as usual and both run together

Comment: there is no need to have it set as an external interruption, then. The external interruption cannot interrupt itself, if it makes sense, so having it set within the loop has the same result.

Comment: This might be for another question, but will I be able to use interrupts on an Atmega16a chip?

Comment: Yes you will. According to the datasheet, there are three pins available for this function:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-8154-8-bit-avr-atmega16a_datasheet.pdf

The description can be found on page 66.

Then again, I think this would be feasible without you going this way. External interrupts are more suitable as an escape route to handle things that occur whilst your controller is busy doing complex and long tasks. If you want your controller only to handle a signal and switch states, it's not very necessary.

Comment: It never occurred to me asking you this... Are you aware that the case 1 of your switch statement is never true? The switch statement does not change the value of the variable _priority_ by itself, you need to alternate its value from 0 to 1 in other statement. I've added a statement to handle the value change. above.

Comment: From what I see on the serial monitor it should work but I can’t try it on real hardware because the other chips won’t arrive until this Friday. I’ll tell you at this moment if it really works